# Como passar uma matriz que foi alocada, para uma função em C?

Tags: c

Boa noite, estou com uma dúvida, que é o seguinte.

-Escreva um programa que aloque dinamicamente uma matriz (de inteiros) de dimensões definidas pelo
usuário. Em seguida, preencha as posições da matriz e imprima todos os elementos. No fim, crie uma
função que receba um valor e, retorne 1 caso o valor esteja na matriz ou retorne 0 caso não esteja na
matriz.

Não sei como passar uma matriz que foi alocada para uma função. 
Eu teria que passar a quantidade de linhas e colunas, para dentro da função eu poder percorrer a matriz com um laço ? ou não seria preciso ? Obg

Fiz o seguinte código: (Obs: Contem erro, não retorna o valor esperado).
Desculpe por não saber adicionar código no fórum, tentei da melhor forma.

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int contem(int **matriz, int linha, int coluna, int num){
 int j, i, r;
 for(i = 0; i<linha; i++){
  for(j = 0; j<coluna; j++){
   if(matriz[i][j] == num){
    r = 1;
   }else{
    r = 0;
   }
  }
 }
 
 return r;
}

int main(){

 int num;
 int **matriz, i, j;
 int linhas, colunas;
 
 printf("Informe a quantidade de linhas da matriz: \n");
 scanf("%d", &linhas);
 printf("Informa a quantidade de colunas da matriz: \n");
 scanf("%d", &colunas);
 
 matriz = (int **)malloc(linhas * sizeof(int*));
 for(i = 0; i< linhas; i++){
  matriz[i] = (int *)malloc(colunas * sizeof(int));
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i<linhas; i++){
  for(j=0; j<colunas; j++){
   scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
  }
 }
 
 printf("\n\nDADOS:\n");
 for(i = 0; i<linhas; i++){
  for(j=0; j<colunas; j++){
   printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 
 printf("Infofme um numero: \n");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 
 printf("%d ", contem(matriz, linhas, colunas, num));
 
 //liberação de memoria.
 for(i = 0; i<linhas; i++){
  free(matriz[i]);
 }
 
 free(matriz);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, utilizei uma matriz com linhas e colunas já definidas, espero ter interpretado corretamente a dúvida e que o código esteja compreensível.

```
int valor_matriz(int mat[][5]);

int main(){

#define LIN 5
#define COL 5

int mat[LIN][COL];
int i,j,r;

for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){  //Preenchendo Matriz
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
   printf("\n");
}

for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){  //Printando Matriz
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
        printf("%8d", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

r= valor_matriz(mat); //Chamado da Função

printf("%d", r);

return 0;

}

int valor_matriz(int mat[][5]){

int x,y;
int n,r;

printf("Digite um valor para verificar na matriz:");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(x=0;x<5;x++){  //Percorre a Matriz em Busca do Valor Digitado
    for(y=0;y<5;y++){
        if(mat[x][y]==n){
            r=1;
            break;  //Ao encontrar,encerra o ciclo pois ja encontrou ao menos um valor igual ao digitado
        }else{
            r=0;  //Nao encontrou o valor na matriz
        }
    }
}


return r;

}
```